# How to draw a triangle and embed html table inside it?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, svg

for some reporting need I want to draw a triangle and inside that place a html table so I will have an output like the following image [image]

I would really appreciate any suggestions on how I can achieve this using `html` or `css` or `svg` or anything , thx in advance

Comment: Your question does not show any effort on your part, as far as what research you might have done, what you have tried in order to do this yourself.  The hover-text on the downvote arrow says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".

Comment: Also see the ["on topic" page in the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), which says, "*3.Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/3uhFA/1/)

HTML:

```
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>13</td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <div class="leftcover"></div>
    <div class="rightcover"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
td{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
}
tr{
    text-align:center;
    background:#ddd;
}
tr td:last-child{
    padding-right:20px;
}
tr td:first-child{
    padding-left:20px;
    border-left:none;
}
div{
    position:relative;
}
.leftcover{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid white;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    top:0;
}
.rightcover{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid white;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    top:0;
}
```

JQuery:

```
var $height = $("table").height();
var $width = $("table").width();
$(".leftcover").css("border-top-width",$height);
$(".leftcover").css("border-right-width",$width/2);
$(".rightcover").css("border-top-width",$height);
$(".rightcover").css("border-left-width",$width/2);
$(".rightcover").css("left",$width/2);
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/3uhFA/1/)

Comment: Agha kheili kheili mamnooon !!! ali bood :)

Answer (score 2):

Divide your triangle in smaller figures.
How to create figures with css http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/